How to Dynamically Create Correct Media URLs for Different Domains in Shopware?
I'm currently working with a system where I need to dynamically generate specific media URLs for products, based on their domain contexts. Here's the structure I'm working with:

ashop.com should resolve to ashop.com/product_media.jpg
ashop.com/de should also resolve to ashop.com/product_media.jpg
cshop.com/shop/public should resolve to cshop.com/shop/public/product_media.jpg
cshop.com/shop/public/de should also resolve to cshop.com/shop/public/product_media.jpg

I'm using Shopware, and when I fetch products using Command, the URLs are determined by the APP_URL defined in the .env file. However, when I attempt to use the domain directly to create image URLs, they do not resolve correctly.
How can I correctly generate the media URL for each specific domain? Is there a pattern or method in Shopware that facilitates this, or will I need to implement a custom solution? Any guidance or examples would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
